# JPA updating children through Parent

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm using JPA, with Spring-Data and Hibernate and would like to update children (OneToMany), the updated list will include new children, updated children and no longer contain children to remove.
Goal: existing children are merged (equals/hashcode is based on id), new children inserted and no longer contained children removed. I now get the following exception:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance
```

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
    
    public void setChildren(Set<Child> children) {
      if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.children)) {
            this.children = children;
        } else {
            this.children.forEach(entry -> entry.setParent(null));
            children.forEach(entry -> entry.setParent(this));
            this.children.clear();
            this.children.addAll(children);
        }
    }
} 

@Entity
public class Child {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;
    
    public void setParent(Parent parent){
    this.parent = parent;
    }
}

    @Service
    @Transactional
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class Service {

    private final JpaParentRepository parentRepository;
    
// this method is used to create a new parent or update an existing parent
    @Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
    public ParentDto createOrUpdate(UUID parentId, ParentDto parentDto) {
        Parent parent = parentRepository.findById(parentId).orElseGet(new Parent(parentId));
        updateParent(parentDto); // some logic to update parent including it's children via setChildren
        
        Parent saved = parentRepository.save(parent);
        
        return convert(saved); //logic to convert to dto
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was straightforward (after trying many different things). Hope this helps someone else or future me :)

```
 public void setChildren(Set<Child> children) {
    this.children.forEach(entry -> entry.setParent(null));
    this.children.clear();
    children.forEach(entry -> entry.setParent(this));
    this.children.addAll(children);
}
```